# remove arguments passed to chrome by selenium / chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with python and chromium / chromedriver. I want to REMOVE switches passed to chrome (e.g. --full-memory-crash-report), but so far I could only find out how to add further switches.

My current setup:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get(someurl)
```

As far as I understand this can be used to add arguments:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--some-switch")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

So, how do I get rid of default arguments or wipe all default arguments clean and pass only a custom list?

Answer (score 4):

It helped me:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["test-type"])
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Found solution here https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007189411--Chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-notification

Answer (score 2):

In C#:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExcludedArgument("test-type"); // To remove arg "--test-type=webdriver"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use excludeSwitches chrome option. See: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome_options.arguments.remove("--some-switch")` to remove an individual option. To wipe it clean use `chrome_options.arguments[:] = []`.

You can check the properties of the chrome_options object with:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint (vars(chrome_options))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Arguments is already empty. I can remove/disable switches that chromedriver sets.